# How to get Quick Filter back in Synaptic [Ubuntu 16.04 and later]

Tags: 16.04, 17.10, synaptic, 18.04

Ubuntu 16.04, Synaptic Package Manager does not have a search box for quick filter. I can use search button, but it opens dialog every time which is really annoying and not convenient.

[image: new synaptic]

I want to have something like this which we used to have in earlier releases.

[image: old synaptic]

Did Ubuntu made this change or has it been changed by Synaptic?
What is the way to get quick filter back in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

you can try a couple of things:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-xapian-index
sudo update-apt-xapian-index -vf
```

If that doesn't work you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall synaptic
sudo dpkg-reconfigure synaptic
```

Hopefully that will take care of your issues.

Comment: The package apt-xapian-index needs to be installed. The filter will eventyally show up. See Lauchpad bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1569156).

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit Synaptic 0.83.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04